# Creating an Order from Quote using Custom Workflow

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-online

I am creating a custom workflow which will trigger when status of a `Quote` will be changed and it will create an `Order` taking all the values from that `Quote` record.

Now Creating an `Order` is the easy part, but get the values from the `Quote` record is not, for me.

Could you please suggest me a way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you can do it without a customer workflow activity.  You'll need to create a customer workflow activity.  You can grab the id from the PrimaryEntityId.  Once you have the Id, you can lookup all of the attributes using the C# SDK and use that information to populate and create your Order.

Comment: Thanks Daryl. One thing more, can I pass the Quote Guid as string?

Comment: @TamalKantiDey I don't believe so.  It's a Guid.  Why would you want it as a string?

Comment: because, the link u send me its not showing any Guid datatype.

Comment: hey Daryl, I just find out I can get the Id from `workflowContext.PrimaryEntityId`. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Why are you doing this rather than simply clicking the "Create Order" button on the Quote form?  That'll suck all the information in the relationship mapping through for you.  And the products.

Comment: to Automate the creation process,so that no need to click the `Create Order` button

Comment: Have you looked at the ConvertQuoteToSalesOrderRequest class?  That could be used in a custom workflow action and could do a lot of what you are trying to achieve.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.crm.sdk.messages.convertquotetosalesorderrequest.aspx